# Discrete Math - Complements

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image: A^C]

I'm trying to figure out why the answer would be everything but 0,2,3 as the universal set is 0-9..

I don't know how to explain that the answer would be {1,4,5,6,7,8,9}

LETTER G

Comment: The answer to what part???

Comment: @ThomasGrubb Sorry, letter g

Comment: The definition of $A^c$ is $U-A$

Comment: so U excluding A meaning everything in A must be gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A^C$ = $U$ - $A$ = Elements which are in set $U$ but not in set $A$.

Hence, $A^C$ = $\{$$1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9$$\}$

Answer (score 1):

The Universal Set is the set that contains everything. So just imagine we are given a a universal set $S$; therefore all we know to exists is in the set $S$. That being said, any set $A$ $\subseteq$ $S$ we know that $A^{C} \cup A = U$ (this should be clear, but if it is not try to prove it). Now that we have this rule it should be clear that if:

$U$ = $\{$$0, 1, 2, \dots, 9$$\}$, A = $\{$$0, 2, 3$$\}$

Then  $A^C$ = $U$ \ $A$ = $\{$$1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9$$\}$

Of course a more formal proof exists, but I hope I have explained intuively why it is.